# Meta-analysis - Multiple Outcome measures for the same population

Tags: meta-analysis, binary-data

Basically, I am trying to include some binary data into a meta-analysis and not sure how to include this dataset.

If you look at the attached table, each red square that i drew depicts an independent sub-group (N=30). Each number represents the total number of children (out of 30) that passed a single cognitive test. Each child was tested on 4 different tests so there are 4 different numbers in each red box.

*I want to compare performance of children in condition 3 to children in condition 4 within each year group (i.e. the blue squares), so this comparison would be independent-measures.* Given that i don't know how each child performed in the 4 tests respectively, i don't know how to combine these values so that i don't have an issue of non-independence of observations.

Specifically, i am interested in the odds of a child succeeding in condition 3 / odds of a child succeeding in condition 4, for each of the three years.

[image]

Comment: An odd ratio between the two conditions ? With age group as a moderator ? I can develop that answer if it seems right.

Comment: I can calculate the odds ratio fine, my only issue is that for each population i have 6/4 odds ratios that i could use. I can't include all of them as if they are coming from the different populations, but i don't know a good way of satisfactorily summing up the data in one effect size since there isn't enough infomation provided (the mean score on the 4 tests reported here would sum it up...)

Comment: I'm not sure I get everything, but I suggest looking up Borenstein (2009) chapter on combining effect sizes coming from a single study.